# deserializing enums

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

I have an xml in which one of the elements has an attribute that can be blank.
For e.g.,

```
<tests>
<test language="">
.....
</test>
</tests>
```

Now, language is enum type in the classes created from the schema. It works fine if the language is specified, it fails to deserialize if it is blank (as shown in example).

Edit: Code for deserialization:

```
XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
StringReader strreader = new StringReader(stringXML);
Object o = serializer.Deserialize(strreader);
```

How can I handle this scenario

Comment: Can you post your deserialization code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<strike>You could declare the enum property as nullable:</strike>

```
public Language? Language { get; set; }
```

---

EDIT: ok, I just tried, it doesn't work for attributes... Here's another option: don't serialize/deserialize this property directly, but serialize a string property instead :

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Language Language { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("Language")]
public string LanguageAsString
{
    get { return Language.ToString(); }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            Language = default(Language);
        }
        else
        {
            Language = (Language)Enum.Parse(typeof(Language), value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That also means you can store a null value there, which is bad encapsulation IMHO. It's better to provide a non-nullable in this case, and convert to a defeault value on the setter.

Comment: This is not the best way as you adapt your model to the technology, and that is not a good thing.

Comment: @Vajda, I know it's not ideal... if you have a better solution, I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, Here is the best way to do this. Just look the example code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx

Comment: @Vajda, I agree it's cleaner, but it's not quite the same... it will always serialize the default value as an empty string, which might not be the desired effect.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, I posted answer below. So you can see.

Comment: You also need to consider @Mike Hofer example below (XmlEnumAttribute) which will cause the Enum.Parse to fail.  And a value like "2" would get parsed to the enum value matching 2 rather than the one matching the XmlEnumAttribute("2") (as another interesting way to fail)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Hi Thomas, could you please help me ? I've posted a new 'answer' to the question because I didn't know how to ask you within a comment and including all the code. Please see my answer below. Thanks !

Comment: I like this answer for deserializing enums that cannot have the XmlEnum attribute. For example: SqlDbType

Answer (score 19):

You probably need to mark up your enumeration, and add a default item that represents Unknown.

For example:

```
Public Enum EmployeeStatus
   <XmlEnum("")> Unknown = 0
   <XmlEnum("Single")> One = 1
   <XmlEnum("Double")> Two = 2
   <XmlEnum("Triple")> Three = 3
End Enum
```

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 19):

You can do it this way:

```
namespace Example
{

   public enum Language
   {
     [XmlEnum("en")]
     English,

     [XmlEnum("de")]
     Deutsch
   }

   public class ExampleClass
   {

      private Language? language;

      [XmlAttribute("Language")]
      public Language Language
      {
         get { return language ?? Example.Language.English; }
         set { language = value; }
      }

      .
      .
      .
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What would you want the result to be ?

A blank value cannot be mapped to a null reference since an enum is a non-nullable value type.

Comment: yeah, I know. but I am thinking what can be workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
object wontBeNull = couldBeNull ?? defaultIfNull;
```

Is what I'd try. It's called [Null-Coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator), I use it when I want a default for null input.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this. I have a property of the enum type, which should deserialized. How do I mention this in the property when I declare it???

Comment: Seriously though, have you considered a try-catch block? If you put one around your deserialization, it can catch many errors and malformed XML files.